# SELECT on tables with . (dot) in tablename (MSSQL/PHP) not working?

Tags: php, sql

I have problems with this simple SELECT command, I've already selected which database in my sql connection string, but it seems to think that the "cellnames" in my table is a database, and "rnc" is the tablename, right?

```
$data = mysql_query("
    SELECT * FROM cellnames.rnc
    ") or die(mysql_error());
```

This outputs:

> "SELECT command denied to user ''@'localhost' for table 'rnc'"

However, the table name is "cellnames", and the column is "rnc". How come it works this way? And what do I need to do to make it work?

I've also tried this:

```
$data = mysql_query("
    SELECT * FROM cellnames
    ") or die(mysql_error());
```

Which results in:

> No database selected

Can this have something to do with it? I've already specified the database in the connection string but perhaps that didn't work? This is my connection string:

```
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"ranos_se");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);
```

Comment: Dots are not permitted in MySQL table names, as it’s the character that separates the database name from the table name, i.e. `[database]`.`[table]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try with `sqlsrv_query` instead of `mysql_query`. As you are using `MSSQL`, not `MYSQL`.

like

```
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"ranos_se");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);
$data = sqlsrv_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM cellnames") or die(sqlsrv_errors());
```

Comment: Doh, of course. I've only used MySQL earlier but now trying to work with a MSSQL server at work. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

As Yograj pointed out, you are using the MySQL library, which is not compatible with SQL Server. You should look into using [PDO_SQLSRV](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-sqlsrv.php) to connect to your database, which is an improvement over the old db_query() functions.